# Json string in Angular ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I get a json string from an `$http` request, and I want to use `ng-repeat` to display the data. As it stands, I get the json string from the server, but ng-repeat is not putting the data on the dom.

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller2">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
    {% csrf_token %}
       Search:<input ng-model="artiste" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <table ng-repeat="artist in artists">
        <tr>
            <td> {({ artist.fields.link })} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
artApp.controller('mycontroller2', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http){
    $scope.submit = function(){
    var call = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/rest/',
        data: {
            "artiste": $scope.artiste
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFTOKEN': "{{ csrf_token }}"
        }
    };
    $http(call)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.artists = data;
        })
    }
}]);
```

The response data that shows up in devtools is a json string

```
"[{\"fields\": {\"artist\": \"Leonardo da Vinci\", \"link\": \"https://trove2.storage.googleapis.com/leonardo-da-vinci/galloping-rider-and-other-figures.jpg\", \"title\": \"Galloping Rider and other figures\"}, \"model\": \"serve.art\", \"pk\": 63057},
```

I thought I could just iterate over it with `ng-repeat` and generate html elements with the data, but it doesn't work right now.

Comment: why using 3 braces..it should be 2 curly braces..so change it as  <td> {{ artist.fields.link }} </td> ..then try?

Comment: This is a Django template. Two curly braces is the Django variable syntax. For angular I have to change the variable syntax to `{({ var })}`

Answer (score 1):

For Json Parsing in angular you have to use the following code in success method.

```
.success(function(data){
    var response=angular.fromJson(data);

    $scope.artists = response.fields;
 })
```

modify your `<table>` as below, Because you have assign the response array to $scope.artists.
Then you can use your json data with individual key.

```
<table ng-repeat="artist in artists">
    <tr>
        <td>{{artist.link}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

check whether the value is getting or not in console.

```
.success(function(data){
    var response=angular.fromJson(data);

    $scope.artists = response.fields;
    console.log("artist :"+$scope.artists.artist);
    console.log("link :"+$scope.artists.link);
 })
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` is still not showing anything on the dom.

Comment: I can see in the breakpoints that the vars `data` and `response.fields` have the json data that I want. It's just not making it over to `ng-repeat`

Comment: I believe the ng-repeat loop is showing a `TypeError` for the data it's iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't JSON.parse just work?

```
$scope.artists = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: That works but the data is not making it to `ng-repeat` for printing to the dom.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. My code works when saving as .html and just running it in the browser, but not when serving it from a simple node.js app. My guess it has something to do with content being served as the wrong type. ng-repeat loops, but doesn't print. Maybe you should be looking in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your html, try :

```
 <td> {({ fields.artist.link.})} </td>
```

instead of artist.fields.link, according to your json : \"fields\": {\"artist\": \"Leonardo da Vinci\", \"link\": \

Comment: That wasn't going to work because my `ng-repeat = "artist in artists"` used `artist` as the iterator, I could change it to `entry in artists` and it still wasn't working. However, the code works now after going away for a few hours, coming back, changing nothing, and trying it again. This keeps happening to me. I don't know if it's something with my browser, but my javascript won't work, then a few hours later it magically works.